# Why are my text shadows not turning off when I use my swap function?

Tags: javascript, css, text

So I am making a "Mini-OS" an OS that works in your browser, and in the "Settings" > "Accessibility" tab I have an option to switch text shadows on / off (default is on). But the text shadows won't turn off, (I am using CSS and JavaScript).

I tried checking for typos, and looking at error logs, but nothing was found. The variable being used as a place holder (ApplyTextShadows) switches its value, but the text shadows don't.

```
//the code to control the shadows
if(ApplyTextShadows == "on") {
    document.write("<style>h2 {text-shadow:5px 10px #8888;}</style>");
}
//the code where the button to toggle the setting
document.write("<h2 onclick=\"swapShadows()\">Text Shadows ("+ApplyTextShadows+")</h2>");
//the function itself
function swapShadows() {
    if(ApplyTextShadows == "on") {
        ApplyTextShadows = "off";
    } else {
        ApplyTextShadows = "on";
    }
    openAccessibility();
}
```

I expected the code to turn the shadows off. But it did nothing.

Comment: You're checking the variable when you first write the stylesheet. Changing the variable doesn't rewrite it.

Comment: BTW, two-state variables should use the boolean type, with values `true` and `false`, not strings like `"on"` and `"off"`.

Comment: @barmar Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class that you add and remove.

```js
function swapShadows() {
  document.querySelectorAll("h2").forEach(el =>
    el.classList.toggle("shadow")
  );
}
```

```css
h2.shadow {
  text-shadow: 5px 10px #8888;
}
```

```html
<h2 onclick="swapShadows()">Text Shadows ("+ApplyTextShadows+")</h2>
```

Comment: thanks, it really helps with my project, if you give me your name I could list you in the credits by your name, but for now the credits for you will display "StackOverflow's - Barmar" :) Thanks again!